# Calendar client with spring security 5 and oauth2

Tags: java, reactjs, google-calendar-api, spring-security-oauth2

I managed to configure google spring security 5 with outh2 to connect to google. I have the ability to save access_token. In the first step of my application we do not request calendar permissions. We do not want to obtain them until later.  I have seen many strange examples using webClient, resttemplate, examples that are already deprected.

I am looking for a solution where I can use access_token and refresh_token for the application to request access to the calendar, and then I can download e.g. events.

I am using  a reactjs. I would like it to redirect me to the google site to give me permission and then be able to download events after another click on the front page.

EDIT:
Answer is:

```
Credential credential = new Credential(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod());
        credential.setAccessToken("your token");
        credential.setRefreshToken("your refresh token");
        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
```

Comment: So essentially you do not want to include the necessary scopes only until retrieving the events is needed? If not, can you provide more information about *what* are you trying to achieve essentially? @Deluxxx

Comment: I would like to give you the opportunity only to connect the calendar and download the events in your settings, not when you first register. @ale13

Comment: Then, just like mentioned below, the incremental authorization seems like the best decision in this situation. Why isn't this an option to you? @Deluxxx

Comment: Ok. I created something like that. I get token with scopes. After granted to calendar. I want to change page and get all events. Not in one question where the authorisation is. Only on the other side, when you click, show me my events. How can I initial credentials correctly? I store acces token.    com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar  client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
     .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

but how init credentials to get events.

Answer (score 0):

Google supports [incremental authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#incrementalAuth), so if you initiate the OAuth flow again with the new permissions and the `include_granted_scopes` parameter set to true, you can add the new permissions onto your existing authorization.

Alternatively, you can use a managed solution like [Xkit](https://xkit.co) to add this kind of integration. It handles the OAuth flow for you (with incremental authorization built in) as well as refresh tokens, and it integrates natively with React. (Disclosure: I work there!)

Comment: Do I really need to use the incremental mode? I can always start a new authorization with an extended list of scopes, right?

Comment: @Alexey yes you can manually track which scopes you've already requested and add more on top of that yourself (without this flag). That's a strategy we (at Xkit) employ with providers that don't have a flag like this.